# posting json from angular2 to restful webapi

Tags: rest, api, angular

I have a question, when I try to post an json object to my restfull api it will not work.

I have searched all over the place and tried already a lot but without succes. Can enyone help me with it, here is the code from angular2

```
postContact(contact: IContact){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(contact);
    return this._http.post(this._contactenlijstUrl, body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe();
```

Here is the code from the webapi

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult VoegPersoonToe([FromBody]JObject test)
        {
            try
            {
              .... Here i have to create a class and import the json object...

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

When I run the code I get this error:

Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
http://localhost:39468/api/contacten/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 415 Unsupported Media Type for URL: http://localhost:39468/api/contacten/
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3462
Subscriber.ts:241Uncaught Response

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass the RequestOptions to the post method, you put the headers instead! Try this:

```
return this._http.post(this._contactenlijstUrl, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe();
```

Comment: I did what you sugest but without good result:Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
2http://localhost:39468/api/contacten/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
nieuwContact:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:39468/api/contacten/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 415
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3462
Subscriber.ts:241Uncaught Response

Comment: The 'preflight' in the error message indicates that you have a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue. Depending on your server and infrastructure the way to handle this may vary.

Comment: It where indeed the CORS in asp.net core that where not set well! Thx for the advice